# Get next rows from selected value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to get next column values from which I selected.

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE round > (
  SELECT round from test
  WHERE b1 = '9' AND b2 = '16' and b3 = '21'
)
ORDER BY round
LIMIT 1
```

I tried this sql code but it returns
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression error...

```
  SELECT round from test
  WHERE b1 = '9' AND b2 = '16' and b3 = '21'
```

this sql returns multiple rows and I want to get all next rows after this selected rows

if my data is looks like

```
round b1   b2   b3  
1     9    16   21
2     2    13   24
3     9    16   21 
4     5    14   22
```

I want to get
(2,2,13,24)(4,5,14,22)
Can I get help?? Thanks

Comment: Which language you are using ? Also do you use ADO or other kind of driver ?

Comment: So, `round` is a primary key, or at least unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c1d929eae91cadbc4bdcb9b9881b42b2)

You can use [`lead()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) which puts the next value to the current record:

```
SELECT
    next_round, next_b1, next_b2, next_b3
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        lead(round) OVER w as next_round,
        lead(b1) OVER w as next_b1,
        lead(b2) OVER w as next_b2,
        lead(b3) OVER w as next_b3
    FROM t
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY round)
) s
WHERE b1 = 9 AND b2 = 16 AND b3 = 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `(NOT) EXISTS()`:

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT round from test nx
        WHERE nx.b1 = '9' AND nx.b2 = '16' and nx.b3 = '21'
        AND nx.round >= t.round
        );
```

---

This will retrieve **all** rows if no matching record(s) exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM test t1 INNER JOIN test t2
ON t1.round > t2.round AND (t1.b1, t1.b2, t1.b3) <> (t2.b1, t2.b2, t2.b3)
WHERE (t2.b1, t2.b2, t2.b3) = (9, 16, 21)
ORDER BY t1.round
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af75270e314e93d661f58ad1514a0173).
Results:

| round | b1 | b2 | b3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 13 | 24 |
| 4 | 5 | 14 | 22 |

Comment: Thank you for help, but I want to just get right next row...
this get all rows after (9,16,21) row